# Resolvent estimate of compact perturbation of self-adjoint operator

Tags: reference-request, sp.spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a selfadjoint operator on Hilbert space $H$. Then we know that there is a resolvent estimation $$\left\lVert (\lambda-T)^{-1}\right\rVert = \frac{1}{dist(\lambda,\sigma(T))}, \ \lambda \in \rho(T).$$
But what if we want to consider the compact perturbation, that is, operator
$A = T+ D,$
where $D$ is a compact operator on $H$. Is there any known results on the resolvent estimate? Does anyone know some related references ? Thank you very much.

Comment: There are lots of standard estimates using variants of the neumann series for bounded $D$. Also for compact $D$ if $A$ has compact resolvent. See the monograph of Kato. https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783662126783?gclid=Cj0KCQiAjszhBRDgARIsAH8KgvfZfy1pgXWKeK7_XZ7WZ2GYZP1J3v0RWeq_juoD3mBvQau15_cVouMaAs6uEALw_wcB

Comment: Can you specify what you are looking for?

Comment: @AndrásBátkai Thank you very much for your comment. I am looking for a bound on $\left\lVert (\lambda - (T + D))^{-1} \right\rVert$, where $T$ is selfadjoint operator and $D$ is a compact operator(we can add more conditions on the operators if it is necessary).  And I hope the bound can involve $dist(\lambda,\sigma(T+D))$, like the one I write above. Or more precisely, I expect a result similar as the one in http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ob/publ/carleman.pdf